# Creating Model to Implement Hierarchical Attention Network for Document CLassification,

Tags: nlp, attention-model, self-attention

I was reading [this paper](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7E./hovy/papers/16HLT-hierarchical-attention-networks.pdf) and came across a problem, during implementation.

During dataset creation, I created batches as 4 dimensional tensor as such( batch_size x document_size x sentence_size x embedding_size).

Now when I pass though the GRU, it says nn.GRU only accept 3D tensors. So my question is what changes should I make to the model or dataset creation?

Thanks in advance.